# ActiveAdmin not recogninzing my user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an Rails 4 application with Active Admin installed, to manage clients and photos from there.

I used the act-as-taggable-on gem to add tags to my app... but I decided I didn't want to use them anymore and had a little trouble to remove the migration files from my database, but with this code (from another answer in stackoverflow), I managed to remove the tag tables:

```
rails generate migration DropTagsTable

class DropTagsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :tagging
    drop_table :tags

  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

And the tables were removed. I left and turned off my computer. Now I returned and my ActiveAdmin deleted all the information I've added to the clients, the clients, photos, everything. And, to make it worst, it deleted all my users. Not even the example@admin.com password: password, is working. I reseted completely and I can't access my admin anymore.

Could anyone help?

Comment: This likely has little to do with ActiveAdmin. What does your `db/schema.rb` look like? Is the `admin_users` table still there? What happens if you run `rails c` and type `AdminUser.all`?

Comment: I removed all active admin stuff from the app and reinstalled it. It's working again.